# Any command to store Git username password without inital prompt

Tags: git, bash

I'm using a git credential store
`git config --global credential.helper wincred`

Is there a git command to pass the username password without prompting the user. Form my bash script is there a command I can use like:
`git credential.helper-store --username ${x} --password ${y}`

Comment: This is why SSH keys were invented...

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the username, at least, with

```
git config credential.<url> "$x"
```

It would be somewhat insecure to specify a password in the same fashion; leave that to the credential helper itself.